# "Parser Error Message: The server tag is not well formed" in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asplinkbutton

I am getting Error in Line 17. But I can't find it out. `

```
Line 15:  <asp:Repeater ID="ArticleRepetear" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnItemCommand="ArticleRepetear_ItemCommand">
Line 16:  <ItemTemplate>
Line 17:  <asp:LinkButton ID="TitleLinkButton" runat="server" OnCommand="TitleLinkButton_Click" CommandArgument="<%#Eval("id").ToString() %>">
Line 18: <h1><%#Eval("title") %></h1>
Line 19: </asp:LinkButton>`
```

What am I missing in the syntax?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Error is with double quotes in `CommandArgument`:-

```
CommandArgument="<%#Eval("id").ToString() %>">
```

Change it to:-

```
CommandArgument='<%#Eval("id").ToString() %>'>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:  `CommandArgument='<%#Eval("id").ToString() %>'`

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="TitleLinkButton" runat="server" 
OnCommand="TitleLinkButton_Click" CommandArgument="<%#Eval("id").ToString() %>">
 <h1><%#Eval("title") %></h1>
</asp:LinkButton>`
```

to

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="TitleLinkButton" runat="server" 
        OnCommand="TitleLinkButton_Click" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id").ToString() %>'>
<h1><%#Eval("title") %></h1></asp:LinkButton>`
```